# How to use interactive_editor when REPL console is run in context of a particular object

Tags: ruby, vim, irb

I am trying to programmatically launch a console such that:

- Its context is bound to a particular object ([link to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189818/how-to-run-irb-start-in-context-of-current-class)).
- It allows me to use tools (i.e. `vim` command) provided by the `interactive_editor` Gem ([link to GitHub](https://github.com/jberkel/interactive_editor)).

It would be appear that the two conditions I am trying to meet are mutually exclusive.  Below I write a script that fires up a REPL that is bound to the context of a `[1,2,3]` list.

```
# test.rb
require 'ripl'
require 'interactive_editor'

Ripl.start :binding => [1,2,3].instance_eval { binding }
```

If you run `ruby test.rb`, you can see that you are in the context of `[1,2,3]`:

```
>> self
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> map { |a| a * 2 }
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

But if you try using `interactive_editor`'s features:

```
>> vim "something"
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

This last line fires up `vim` and actually writes to the file "something" (without my explicit saving):

```
# something
---
- 1
- 2
- 3
```

Is there any way for me to resolve this problem?  Should I file this as an issue on the `interactive_editor` Gem?  The same kinds of error occur when I use `IRB` along with `interactive_editor` or `irbtools`.

My guess is that changing the context makes it rather difficult for `interactive_editor` to resolve its object definitions but I am not sure how this works.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if I omitted important information.

1. `ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]`
2. `iteractive_editor (0.0.10)`
3. `irbtools (2.0.1, 1.7.1)`
4. `ripl (0.7.1)`
5. `ripltools (0.7.0)`

I am running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 but have managed to replicate this issue on several other Linux boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this:

```
def edit(*args)
  system("$EDITOR #{args.join(' ')")
end
```

This still doesn't explain why I can't get this example to work with `interactive_prompt`.